# React native deep linking unwanted component renders even with cleanup function

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, deep-linking

I'm facing a problem with my deep linking handle URL, which is my component renders many times after URL come to my app. in other words suppose browser opens up for a purchase action after client choose the desired session time (which handle by a state) and after client decide to do the purchase or cancel it, application opens up for showing the result but it does it multiple times.

here's part of the component :

```
const bookingHandler = () => {
    if(selected == null) {
      Alert.alert('Invalid Selection', 'Please select one of the sessions!')
      return;
    }
    Linking.openURL('http://www.medicalbookingapp.cloudsite.ir/sendPay.php');
  }

  selectedTimeIndex = therapists.meetingPlans[selectedPlanIndex].times.findIndex((el) => el.time == selected.title);
 
  useEffect(() => {

    Linking.addEventListener('url', (e) => handleOpenUrl(e.url))

    return () => {
      Linking.removeEventListener('url', (e) => handleOpenUrl(e.url));
      console.log('event removed')
    } 
    
  });

  const handleOpenUrl = (url) => { 
    const route = url.replace(/.*?:\/\/\w*:\w*\/\W/g, '') // exp://myapplication.... --> ''
    const id = route.split('=')[1]
    
    if(id == 1) {
      dispatch(
        BookingActions.addBooking(
          therapistId,
          therapistFirstName,
          therapistLastName,
          selected.title,
          moment(selectedDate).format("YYYY-MMM-DD"),
          selected.slots,
        )
      );
      

      dispatch(
        doctorActions.updateTherapists(therapistId, selected.slots, selectedDate, selected.title, selectedPlanIndex, selectedTimeIndex)
      );
      setBookingConfirm(true)
      toggleModal();

    } else if(id == 0) {
      console.log('purchase failed...');
      toggleModal();
    }
  }
```

I handle my listener inside the `useEffect` hook and also it has cleanup function. but in console I get this error:

```
Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in %s.%s, a useEffect cleanup function.
```

also I noticed something else, for sake of grasping the problem you can see component screen, and the session select part is handled with `state`. the number of rendering `useEffect` hook is somehow related to the number of change on the select session state. (I mean if I bounce around the select session, it will render more )

[image]

if you need more information just let me know in comments.
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Javascript will treat both event listener callback as seperate entity (reason: object reference). To solve this, Declare callback function outside and pass it to addEventListener and removeEventListener.

Comment: @HarinderSingh Thank you bro. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible issue is you could be creating two handlers, one in addListener and another one in removeListener.

Could you try:

```js
const handler = (e) => handleOpenUrl(e.url);
Linking.addEventListener('url', handler);

return () => {
   Linking.removeEventListener('url', handler);
   console.log('event removed')
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate it, can you please tell me ( like im 5 ) what is the problem with having the handler inside the eventListener ?